# Which serialization to use for my c# objects to save them in a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, xml, serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm looking for some advice, it may be that there is no hard and fast answer but any thoughts are appreciated.  The application is very typical. Its a c# code, currently using VS2010. This code is used amongst other things for providing data from a model to end users.  The model itself is based on some known data at fixed points (a "cube") various parameters and settings. In standard programming practice the user accesses the data via public "get" functions which in turn rely on private member variables such as the known data and the settings.  So far so standard. Now I want to save the class providing this data to the users into an sql database - primarily so all users can share the same data (or more precisely model generated data).

Of course I could just take each member variable of the class and write these into the db using sql database and reinstantiate the class from these.  But I dont want to miss out on all the goodies .net & c# has to offer.  So what I'm thinking of doing is serializing the object and using linq to sql to squirt this into the db. The linq to sql section is straightforward, but I'm a total newbie when it comes to serialization and I'm a bit concerned/confused about it. It seems the obvious thing is to format the object into xml and write this into the database as a column in the table with sql datatype "xml".  But that leaves me with a few questions.

To my understanding the standard XMLserializer will only write the public members of the class into the xml.  That looks like a non-starter to me since my class design is predicated on keeping much of the class private (writing classes with all public members is outside of my experience - who does that ?). This has led me to consider the DataContractSerializer in which you can opt-in variables for serialization.  However this seems to have some WCF dependencies and I'm wondering what are the potential drawbacks of using it.  Additionally there is the SoapFormatter, which seems to be more prevalent for web applications and also JSON. I'm not really considering these, but maybe I should ? Maybe there are better ways of solving the problem ? Perhaps a bit verbose but hopefully all the context can help so people can shoot me some advice.

Comment: Have you considered creating a mapping class that accepts one of your models & expressly exists to map it to and from the DB?

Comment: Yes - I did something like that before with individual writes to the database for each member - adding up to some nasty latency. But I suppose you could actually have the mapper as you suggest as a "bespoke serializer", just lumping everything into a single blob and dump that in the db. I'm basically lazy and wanted to use the built-in functionality.

Comment: take a look at Dapper, it's a lightweight ORM that tends to be faster than LinqToSQL or most of the other ORMs out there.http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Comment: Thanks will definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have had requirements similar to yours and have done quite a bit of research in this area. I did a number of proof-of-concept projects using XMLSerialization, JSON, BinraryFormatter and not to forget some home grown hacks. I had almost decided to go with JSON (JSON.NET), until I found [protobuf-net](http://www.google.ae/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fprotobuf-net%2F&ei=NhzQUY_4GIuIrgeD-YCgAQ&usg=AFQjCNED9rBjO40OTE7lOqea_rCnfa1Gsg)! It is fast, small in size, version independent, supports inheritance and easy to implement without much changes to your code. Recommend heavily.

Comment: Querying (linq/SQL) is something I am not bothered about in my application. I have other parameters using which I identify my serialized object in question. Forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

If you store an object as XML, it will be very hard to use from the database.  For example, if you store customer objects as XML, how would you write the following?

```
select * from Customers where LastName = 'Obama'
```

It can be done, but it's not easy.

How to map objects to a database is a subject of some controversy. Frameworks that are easy to get started with can become overly complex in the application's later life.  Since most applications spend more time in maintenance than in initial development, I'd use the simplest model that works.

Plain ADO.NET or [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) are good contenders.  You'll write a bit more boilerplate code, but the decrease in complexity more than makes up for that.